# visual webpart custom controls

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-web-part

I need to get list names in drop down in properties when we edit webpart.
Is it possible to get the dynamic values into the drop down control there?

We can get the static values by writing the enum like

```
public enum Controls
{
first,
second,
third
}
```

So can i get these values coming from something like an array?